# Iterate through the items in a Listbox

Tags: c#

I have a ListBox (`sortedListBox`) which I have populated like this by the items in a Combobox (`allItemsComboBox`):

```
int index = sortedListBox.FindString(allItemsComboBox.Text, -1);
if (index == -1)
{
    var item=new { Text = allItemsComboBox.Text , Value = allItemsComboBox.Value};
    sortedListBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The `DisplayedMember` of `sortedListBox` is "Text" and `ValueMember` of it is "Value".

Now I want to iterate through all items in the ListBox and get its values:

```
public static string ListBoxToString(ListBox lb)
{
    List<string> values = new List<string>();            
    for (int i = 0; i < lb.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        values.Add(lb.Items[i].ToString());  
    }

    string result = String.Join(",", values);
    return result;
}
```

In this line: `values.Add(lb.Items[i].ToString());`  I get:

```
{ Text = "Size" , Value = "cte1.Size"}
```

I just want to have the value , which is "cte1.Size"

How can I iterate through the items in the ListBox and get the `ValueMember` of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there's any way to ask the `ListBox` to evaluate the `ValueMember` for you in that way... and because you're using an anonymous type, it becomes harder to *get* the value.

Options:

- Use a named type instead, and cast each item to that
- Use dynamic typing

For example:

```
public static string ListBoxToString(ListBox lb)
{
    var values = lb.Items
                   .Cast<dynamic>()
                   .Select(x => x.Value.ToString());
    return string.Join(",", values);
}
```

Dynamic typing provides the most *immediate* fix, but I'd strongly encourage you to consider using a custom type. (It needn't take more than a few lines to write.)

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @nnmmss: Is that with my exact code? That seems unlikely, as there isn't a conversion to `List<string>` there...

Comment: public static string ListBoxToString(ListBox lb)
        {           
            List<string> values = lb.Items
                    .Cast<string>()
                   .Select(x => x.Value.ToString());
            string result = String.Join(",", values);
            return result;
        }

Comment: Jon Skeet uses `var values = lb.Items ...`, the actual type is `IEnumerable<string>` and not `List<string>`.

Comment: @nnmmss: Well that's not the code I used, is it? I used `var`, which will implicitly type the result as `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. Why not just use the code that I posted?

Comment: @Dirk: It's actually `IEnumerable<dynamic>` in this particular case, due to the dynamic evaluation. We could make it `IEnumerable<string>` by adding a cast though.

Comment: @Jon Skeet the select doesn't return string in that case because x.Value is dynamic too?

Comment: sorry you are right   :  public static string ListBoxToString(ListBox lb)
        {            
            var values = lb.Items
                    .Cast<string>()
                   .Select(x => x.Value.ToString());
           return string.Join(",", values);
        }  : but i got  Error 2 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @nnmmss: See where you've got `Cast<string>`? Now look at my code. Why don't you just *copy and paste my code*? It works, I've tried it. I'm not going to claim that anything that *isn't* my code works though.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your approach:

1.) The `ListBox` stores items as a collection of `objects` which means accessing them with `listBox.Items[idx]` will only give you back an `object` and not the actual type. You could get around that with casting it to the appropriate type but it won't work in your case because of the next point.

2.) You create your items as anonymous objects with `var item = new { ... }`. You can't cast to this kind of type. You *could* use the `dynamic` keyword to get around that but I wouldn't do that as you lose type safety.

What you could do is create a simple class for the date you want to store and use that instead of an anonymous type:

```
class MyData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```